# electron-localshortcut not working without providing Browser Window

Tags: javascript, electron

`electon-localshortcut` giving error when I am trying to assign shortcut without specifying any browser window as given in https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-localshortcut

```
electronLocalshortcut.register('CmdOrCtrl+Alt+Super+Right', () => {
        console.log('move captured')
    })
```

Following is the error shown:

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: win.on is not a function
    at register (/home/user/myapp/node_modules/electron-localshortcut/index.js:68:7)
    at Object.register (/home/user/myapp/node_modules/electron-localshortcut/index.js:51:3)
    at setAppLevelShortcuts (/home/user/myapp/main.js:65:24)
    at App.startUp (/home/user/myapp/main.js:39:2)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at App.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

It seems `window` is a necessary parameter but in the link its given that shortcut can be registered without giving any window also.

Comment: When do you want to press this shortcut? Do you want a global shortcut?

Comment: Not a system wide global shortcut. Shortcut is to be added in application only but not specific to any Browser Window. I have multiple browser windows and shortcut should apply irrespective of focused window.

Comment: Please see my edit for another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

Register `electron-localshortcut` on all the windows then when it get's pressed then run a function that checks for the focused window like this:

```
var win1 = new BrowserWindow({title: "Win 1"});
var win2 = new BrowserWindow({title: "Win 2"});

electronLocalshortcut.register(win1, 'CmdOrCtrl+Alt+Super+Right', () => {
    shortcutPressed();
});

electronLocalshortcut.register(win2, 'CmdOrCtrl+Alt+Super+Right', () => {
    shortcutPressed();
});

function shortcutPressed () {
    var focusedWin = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    console.log("Shortcut pressed on " + focusedWin.getTitle());
}
```

### Option 2

Add a invisible menu item then set the `accelerator` option to `'CmdOrCtrl+Alt+Super+Right'` like this:

```
{
    accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Alt+Super+Right'
    visible:     false,
    click:       function () {
        shortcutPressed();
    }
}
```

(This doesn't work on OSX because it needs to be visible for the shortcut to work)

Comment: Thats what I want to avoid. In the link I gave above, there are functions without window parameter also. Are not they ones which can be used.

Comment: I think those ones are for global shortcuts so they will fire wether or not the windows are focused

Comment: Thanks. will try second option. I don't have problem with menu.

Comment: I am yet to try this. Will surely update afterwards.